# Updating Paypal Subscription Payment Method using Vault

Tags: rest, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I need to implement a feature that allows users to update their subscription payment method (credit card) using Paypal rest API.
I've been browsing the documentation for the Subscription api, but I'm having trouble figuring out the exact steps to achieve this. Can someone provide guidance on how to update a customer's subscription payment method using the paypal API?